# Return data from VIEWS using Knex.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, knex.js

How can I get data from views in my mysql database using knex.js ?

I want to return this data in my nodejs route.get

```
SELECT c.id, nome_1 
  FROM pessoas_juridicas as pj
  INNER JOIN pessoas as p
      ON p.id = pj.pessoa_id
  INNER JOIN clientes as c
      ON c.pessoa_id = pj.pessoa_id
UNION 

SELECT c.id, nome_1 
  FROM pessoas_fisicas as pf
  INNER JOIN pessoas as p
      ON p.id = pf.pessoa_id
  INNER JOIN clientes as c
      ON c.pessoa_id = pf.pessoa_id

 WHERE p.id = 1
 ;
```

Comment: Views can be queries just like tables - just use the view name instead of a table name

Comment: Thanks, I could do this minutes after my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
let sql = knex.from('live_calls' + ' as r')
        .select('r.uuid', 'r.destination', 'r.current_status', 'r.src')
        .where('r.uuid', '=', uuid );
  
    sql.then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
     });
```

Here **live_calls** is a MySQL View.